# Не печатает принтер Canon TS5040 на Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

Установил драйвер в автоматическом режиме через настройки.
При попытке что-либо напечатать LibreOffice сначала зависает, а затем выдает ошибку `"Невозможно запустить принтер. Проверьте конфигурацию принтера".`
Как можно устранить это?[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Можно поставить Windows и MS Office.

Comment: и откуда только у тебя такая репутация в профиле...

Comment: Смотрите драйвера на офсайте Canon, может есть; либо им в техподдержку напишите.